# confusion between u-boot.elf and u-boot

Tags: linux-kernel, xilinx, u-boot, arm64

1. Installed Vivado 2018.2
2. Clone u-boot git clone https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx.git
3. change directory to u-boot-xlnx
4. source /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2018.2/settings64.sh
5. export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
6. export ARCH=aarch64
7. make avnet_ultra96_rev1_defconfig
8. make

Both u-boot and u-boot.elf appear at the directory, what they are?
I want to build a boot.bin from fsbl.elf, xxxx.bit and u-boot.elf with SDK, which file shall I use?

---

I search the issue on web but get difference answer, someone recommends that rename the u-boot to u-boot.elf and apply it, other says use the u-boot.elf directly.

Your answer is welcome, thanks a lot.

Comment: My board is ultra96 v2, I use minicom get output from USB-COM, host system is Ubuntu 18.
I try the two files, when I add u-boot.elf, I only can get output from fsbl.elf. When I try renanme u-boot and apply it, I get "No valid device tree binary found..." after the fsbl finish.